# git diff between the latest commit and the last one I did

Tags: git, shell, hash, diff, alias

so, I can easily get the diff between two commits by using

> git diff hash_old hash_new file

that works, but in my current workflow my diffs are invariably between the latest commit and my commit. is there a way to automate that with a shell alias so that i don't have to manually copy the two hashes but instead always pick the latest with my name or email and compare it against the latest in line?

I tried to do this by subsetting the output of git diff through a shell function and then creating an alias, but not sure the output is stored as an array. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the shortest solution and also the one that is most stable because it uses the low-level helper command for history traversal):

```
git diff $(git rev-list --author="Your Name" -1 HEAD) HEAD
```

Comment: Minor glitch, the `git rev-list` needs a `HEAD` as well: `git diff $(git rev-list --author=... -1 HEAD) HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h" --author=<name> | xargs git diff
```

Replace `<name>` with your `git user-name`.